# Opening reports in Access filtering on multiple fields

Tags: ms-access, filter

I am trying to open a report in MS Access 2010 that has been filtered based on nine possible fields on a form; however, if one of those fields is empty, I want the filter to ignore that field. I was able to do this based on 3 possible fields by using a combination 6 "if statements" going through all the possibilities of combinations to see if the specified combination of fields had information, then filter on those specified fields. That's easy to do if there are only 3 fields.

I now want to now do that same thing with 9 fields on the form but that would require 362,880 combinations of "if statements". Is there another way to open a report and filter it based on multiple fields only if those fields have information in them?

Comment: Are you opening the report with `DoCmd.OpenReport` and a *WhereCondition*?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm doing it. The problem is that it doesn't ignore empty fields but rather filters to the fields that are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine each of your search text boxes and build a *WhereCondition* string based on only those whose values are not Null.

This example is based on only 2 text boxes but can be easily extended to more.

```vb
Dim strWhereCondition As String
If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchID) Then
    ' ID is numeric datatype
    strWhereCondition = strWhereCondition & " AND ID=" & Me.txtSearchID.Value
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchDept) Then
    ' Dept is text datatype
    strWhereCondition = strWhereCondition & " AND Dept='" & Me.txtSearchDept.Value & "'"
End If
If Len(strWhereCondition) > 0 Then
    ' discard leading " AND "
    strWhereCondition = Mid(strWhereCondition, 6)
End If
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFoo", WhereCondition:=strWhereCondition
```